# Can not deserialize instance out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to map the response of a service (json) to an object.

Returned json value for when there is available data:

```
{
    "phone": "0712123123",
    "username": "aaa@bbb.com",
    "lastName": "aaa",
    "firstName": "bbb",
    "address": "New address",
    "email": "aaa@bbb.com",
    "notificationSettings": [
        {
            "eventType": "a1",
            "email": true,
            "notification": true,
        },
        {
            "eventType": "a2",
            "email": true,
            "notification": true,
        }
     ]
}
```

Returned value for when there is no available data for that user:

```
[]
```

The service call is below:

```
public UserDataDto getUserInfoService(String xAuthToken) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("XAuth", xAuthToken);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);
        try {
            ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    baseUrl + getUserInfo, 
                    HttpMethod.GET, 
                    httpEntity, 
                    UserDataDtoDto.class, 
                    version);
            return (UserDataDto) response.getBody();
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            handleException(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I have read the other responses for similar problems and I know that the method expects an object {} and it receives an array [] when there is no available data for the given user, hence the exception. I know that replacing the UserDataDto with UserDataDto[] would solve this particular problem.

My question is how do I avoid making a new method just for this single scenario. Is there a way to update the current method so that it works for both cases: user with or without information.

Comment: You should return a 404 if there's nothing available.

Comment: Sadly I'm no the one implementing the service. Sorry I didn't mention it, I'm writing the automated tests. Please consider no changes can be made to the service.

Comment: Just for the record: if your user guide says that this is the expected behavior; then yes, you have to adapt your tests here. But if the service isn't clearly spec'ed; then you should turn to the owners of that service and make sure that the observed behavior is what they want (and what other services do). You see: you are the tester; if you find something to be really broken, the people owning that service better listen to you (and change their service accordingly if it makes sense).

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for the comment. This is the case where the service is performing as expected and the result and its format is approved by all involved parties.